# Cannot use Swift array's first() method

Tags: swift, swift3

So, I have this simple code

```
let arr = [8, 0, 2, 4]
let result = arr.first(where: { $0 == someparam })
print(result)
```

and, I'm getting the error

> cannot call value of non-function type 'Int?'

This is because the Array class has an instance property ***first***

I have searched a lot on the swift documentation site, but I can't find anything that states how I should call this method correctly.

Even more, I can't understand how the Array class has a property and a method instance with the same name

[Swift's official api on the 'first()' method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1848165-first)

[Swift's official api on the 'first' property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1689165-first)

Comment: What's `someparam`? Compiles fine for me with a `someparam` of type `Int`.

Comment: first() with parenthesis is a method.  

 first without parenthesis is a property.  

first is overloaded with its parameters as the differentiating factor by Apple.

The first() method looks for the 1st occurrence of an element that matches your predicate, whereas the first property will return the very 1st element of the array.

Comment: I had the same problem. The error message misleading. I had something wrong within the lambda (closure). I rewrote the closure and it works now.

Comment: In my case I put "=" instead of "==" inside the where comparison. Just ignore misleading error message and carefully inspect you closure for any syntax errors. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the type of `someparam` is `Int`:

```
let arr = [8, 0, 2, 4]
let someparam = 2
let result = arr.first(where: { $0 == someparam })
print(result!)
```

**Out:**
2

This works correctly.

Targeting your question about why is it possible to have a method and an instance variable with the same name? Well, `first(predicate:)` is an instance method that takes a parameter, while `first` is an instance property.

I think your confusion comes because it is not valid to do the following:

```
struct MyStruct {
    var myProperty: Int? {
        return 2
    }

    func myProperty() {
        print("Hello")
    }
}
```

I think in this case compiler has trouble trying to figure out which is which. However, the following is valid:

```
struct MyStruct {
    var myProperty: Int? {
        return 2
    }

    func myProperty(number: Int) {
        print("Hello \(number)")
    }
}
```

and as you can see, the difference is that this time the method has a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Also note that if you have a syntax error in your **where** closure, you get the same unhelpful error:

> cannot call value of non-function type 'Int?'

The original poster's code was fixed by the answer's declaration of someparam:

```
let someparam = 2
```

I'm guessing that a syntax error in the closure leads swift to think you are using the property incorrectly, instead of the function incorrectly.